# hbase to hive integration failure

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata, hiveql

I have row, column family h1 with two values id and name in "hbase" table 
"hbase_sample".
I want to create external table in hive with id and name columns , i don't 
want to write row or key field.

```
hive> create external table sample (id string,name string)
    > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    > with serdeproperties ("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,h1:id,h1:name")
    > tblproperties("hbase.table.name"="sample_hbase");

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: 
MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe: columns has 2 elements while 
hbase.columns.mapping has 3 elements (counting the key if implicit))
```

Answer (score 0):

By seeing error message, seems like HBase have three columns like rowid, id and name. While you are creating hive table with two columns i.e. id and name.
Create Hive table with all three columns and name it as table_name_temp table. Once temp table is there, create two column table from temp table in hive and then delete temp table. See if this solution works for you.

Comment: That will work , but i dont want to write the key(rowid) column in hive table as it is having some ascii values and that resulting to incorrect format in hive table data. So i want to skip first column.

Comment: You can have original table with three column as a temp table and from the temp table create new table with selected two columns and drop temp table.

Comment: but when loading original table its not loading in proper format because of ascii values. Thats the issue.

Comment: Row id is hash value and that is not problem, issue is you are trying fix three column table in another two column table and that is issue, see the error message, error is for that.

Comment: the main issue here is reading ascii characters from hbase file